# Aggregate recurring document property in Firestore query

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to aggregate recurring document property in a collection from a query?

For example, a car collection contains a list of documents with `carMake` and `carMakeModel`. The property `carMake` can contain Honda, Ford, Toyota, and so on... while `carMakeModel` contains the model of the car i.e. Civic, Prius...

[image: car collection]

With that sample, is there a way to query `car` collection displaying only `carMake` and aggregating similar entries so it won't appear again on the query result?

What I'm currently doing at present is maintaining a separate `carMake` collection. I'm curious if there's something more efficient than that.

[image: carMake collection]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to read all cars and then aggregate the makes, the problem with that is that you'll have to do it in your application code. Firestore does not have server-side aggregation capabilities built-in.

The common solution to prevent reading all cars to determine the makes (which typically is much less data), is precisely what you're doing: storing a separate document or collection with just the list of car makes.

To keep this derived list of car makes up to date, you can either write them from client-side code whenever you also write a car, *or* you can use Cloud Functions to trigger automatically when a car is written and then update the corresponding make.